# Возможна ли такая авторская пунтуация?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть две строчки из стихотворения. Можно ли так оставить запятую перед словом "пустой"?

Где душа твоя теперь, любимый мой?
Вот уж год прошел, пустой....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Можно ли так оставить запятую перед
> словом "пустой"?

Если автор считает, что лучше с запятой, то можно и оставить.

См.:

> § 48… Нераспространенные определения,
> относящиеся к существительным, не
> имеющим впереди определений,
> обособляются, только если они имеют
> пояснительно-конкретизирующее
> значение: *Я часто находил у себя
> записки, короткие и тревожные* (Ч.);
> *Утром он разворачивает газету, местную* (Сол.); Распахиваю в ночь,
> *черную, звездную, соррентийскую, створку окна* (Цвет.).
>
> http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118